# zonal_stats returns PROJ error

Tags: python, proj, zonal-statistics

I have been using `zonal_stats` from the `rasterstats` module for quite some time in Python. And I have never come across this error, which I tried to Google to find some solution with no success.

```
CPLE_AppDefinedError: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

It turns out when I tried to import the module it says:

```
In [1]: from rasterstats import zonal_stats
PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

I am using Anaconda 3/Spyder with Python 3.6.10. My OS is Windows 10. I have tried to update the packages `rasterstats` and `rasterio` with no luck.

Can someone help me 'how to find proj.db'?

Comment: SQLite database proj.db keeps the parameters for the coordinate operations in Proj version 6 and later. Read for example https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn. The proj.db file is supposed to be in the PROJ_LIB directory and you are supposed to have PROJ_LIB environment parameter set.

Comment: Let’s say I don’t have this PROJ_LIB set. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If you use Linux https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/, on Windows `set PROJ_LIB=path_to_the_directory`.

Comment: Hi again @user30184. I can tell I am way too dumb to set this parameter. I am on Windows, so what exactly do I have to do, step by step? Where do I type ‘set PROJ_LIB=path_to_the_directory’ and what is the default directory?

Comment: Hi again @user30184. I figured it out, thanks to you! I located the default directory for proj.db, which is C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj. So whenever I start a new Python document I can use `import os` and then `os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\proj\\'`. I have no idea how to set the global variable. But thanks - just post a short answer, then you'll get the points

Comment: You can also write your findings as an answer yourself. See for example https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/ about how to set global variables. But it may be actually better to set the proj_lib explicitly for your Python session because on Windows you may have Proj installed in many places and after some update the global variable may give you wrong Proj version and you would not notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I figured it out myself thanks to some good advice from @user30184

You have to know or figure out where the file proj.db is located on your system. For me that use Windows 10 as OS, it was located in this directory: C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj.

So whenever I am starting a new Python file, using the `rasterstats` module I will put these two lines in at the beginning. And then the package can be imported:

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\proj\\'
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
```

You can probably set the global variable as well. @user30184 suggested this site: [techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10](http://techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10)